# Invalid Identifier Error when calling a snowflake stored proc with parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parameter-passing

Please help me to figure out why I am getting this error:
*SQL Error [904] [42000]: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 5 at position 1 : SQL     compilation error: error line 1 at position 12
invalid identifier 'D'*
when execute this st.proc as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Myproc(X varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$
BEGIN
RETURN X;
END;
$$;

BEGIN
LET D VARCHAR(128) := 'T1'; 
LET L VARCHAR(128) := '';
CALL Myproc(D) INTO L;
RETURN D||'-'||L;
END;
```

or

```
BEGIN
LET D VARCHAR(128) := 'T1'; 
LET L VARCHAR(128) := '';
CALL Myproc(X => D) INTO L;
RETURN D||'-'||L;
END;
```

Thanks.

I run it in DBeaver via URL connection.
The same error when I try named argument:

It works Ok if I call it with a constant like:

```
BEGIN
LET L VARCHAR(128) := '';
CALL Myproc('T1') INTO L;
RETURN L;
END;
```

Comment: Hi - I’m guessing it’s because that’s not how you reference variables in a SQL statements: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NickW,
this works:

```
BEGIN
LET D VARCHAR(128) := 'T1'; 
LET L VARCHAR(128) := '';
CALL Myproc(X => :D) INTO L;
RETURN D||'-'||L;
END;
```

Apparently, the CALL is treated as SQL statement and requires binding.